# Writing desktop client that can listen to http requests

Tags: http, firewall, tunneling

I would like to write a desktop client that listens to http requests on some port.
How can it be done even though the user that hosts the files is behind a firewall? Is there a way to somehow tunnel the connection from one client to another without involving the server side? Or maybe just involve the server side for some kind of redirect? (Can it be done without a proxy?)

Answer (score 1):

[UDT](http://udt.sf.net)  has a rendezvous method which is firewall friendly and lets you connect two hosts both of which are behind firewall.

However, the two end hosts need to agree on a time and port number and they should send connection initiation packets at about the same time.
In theory, HTTP can be implemented on top of UDT (instead of TCP).
Look at UDT's documentations and papers (all available on its website) for more info.